# Encontrei estas duas expressões "Filho de peixe, peixinho é "e "filho de peixe sabe nadar" São utilizadas em Brasil e Portugal?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões, português-europeu, ditado-popular

Encontrei estas duas expressões "Filho de peixe, peixinho é "e "filho de peixe sabe nadar" são equivalentes . Possivelmente a primeira é mais utilizada no Brasil?!

Qual a sua origem Portugal ou Brasil?

Comment: Penso que a segunda é de Portugal e a primeira mais utilizada no Brasil. Será?1

Comment: Sou do Brasil. Já ouvi consideravelmente a primeira e nunca ouvi a segunda.

Comment: Já ouvi as duas, sendo que a primeira bem mais do que a segunda.   Mas não me recordo se ouvi a segunda no Brasil ou em Portugal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira é mais usada no Brasil e a segunda em Portugal, moro no Brasil e nunca ouvi falar da segunda, mas pelo que pude buscar ambas tem o mesmo significado: os filhos tem semelhanças com os pais. Supõe-se que sejam as suas origens.

Comment: Em Portugal também só ouvi a segunda.

Comment: Renandmc, bem-vindo ao Portuguese StackExchange! Obrigado pela resposta, mas neste site tentamos sempre referenciar o que dizemos, salvo as coisas que todos já sabem ou derivações lógicas óbvias. Falo, pois uma resposta sem referências, como a tua, tem a mesma força desta: “a primeira é burra e segunda é legal”. Obrigado pela resposta de qualquer modo.

Answer (score 1):

Sou do Brasil.
O mais comum utilizado aqui é a primeira sentença. Porém, ambas possuem o mesmo significado: pais e filhos têm semelhanças, tanto fisicamente, quanto no seu comportamento.
EX.: a filha foi suspensa na escola por brigar com o colega. Seu pai havia feito isso no passado. Neste caso, pode-se afirmar que "filho de peixe, peixinho é."